# Javascript: Math.random

Tags: javascript, math

If num parameter is 52, how many possible return values are there? is it 52 or 53? If I understand this correctly, Math.random uses random values from 0 to 1 inclusive. If so, then 0 is a possible return value and so is 52. This results in 53 possible return values. Is this correct? Reason I ask is that a book that I'm learning from uses this code for a deck of cards. I wonder if num should equal 51 ?

Thanks ...

```
function getRandom(num) {
    var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random * num);
    return my_num;
};
```

Comment: It's zero to one, *inclusive* of zero but *exclusive* of one.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies below. Pointy hit it as did others below. 1 is not inclusive (this was my misunderstanding, I thought 0 and 1 were both inclusive) so that makes all returns 0 to 51 or a total of 52 return values ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * num) // note random() is a function.
```

This will return all integers from 0 (including 0) to `num` (NOT including `num`).

`Math.random` returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Multiplying the result by X gives you between 0 (inclusive) and X (exclusive). Adding or subtracting X shifts the range by +-X.

Here's some handy functions from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
// Returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}

// Returns a random number between min and max
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Math.random` returns a real number between `[0,1)` (`1` is **not** inclusive), multiplying the result returns a real number between `[0, 52)`.

Since you are flooring the result, the maximum number returned is `51` and there are `52` distinct values (counting `0`).

Comment: He's got a call to `Math.floor()` in there ... also he's not actually *calling* `Math.random`!

Comment: @Pointy: Right, just noticed that. I guess not calling the function is a typo, since he said he got the code from a book. Or the error is in the book, which is more concerning.

Answer (score 2):

Since value of Math.random varies from 0 to 1(exclusive);
so if you pass 52 in getRandom, return value will vary from 0 to 52(exclusive). so getRandom can return only 52 values. as you are using Math.floor. the max value can be returned is 51.